# そんな飲み方をしてしまいたくなるのが interpreting してしまいたくなる

Tags: grammar

今、ちょっと休憩です。今日もまた、7時まで頑張ります！そして、また、お茶ミルについてですけど、本当に買ってよかった。今、休憩で、また抹茶を作りました。そして、おろししょうががあったので、半分入れた。そんな飲み方、え～ってかんじだけど、**そんな飲み方をしてしまいたくなるのが、このお茶ミルです**。

Can someone help me parse the last sentence, im having trouble on understanding it. I know the たく comes from たい so the たくなる means you want it to come to ~~ But im not really sure on what 飲み方をしてしまいたくなるのが is supposed to mean.

Comment: This might be of help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21026/%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%86-as-an-auxiliary-verb

Comment: する→して＋しまう→してしまいたい→してしまいたく

Comment: I see. Thank you @Garbaz. Despite this I am having a hard time understanding the meaning of this sentence. Is 飲み方 referring to the way the drink is made? Is the writer trying to say they didn't expect that they would make the drink this way? Im not sure how to interpret it sorry.

Comment: I would translate it as "ending up craving to drink it this way" or something like that. Though I'm not entirely confident with my understanding of the surrounding context.
In terms of grammar, think it through one conjugation at a time from left to right.

Comment: @Garbaz してしまう i believe is when a result happens unexpectedly or finished completely, which is why the いたい part is confusing me not sure what the writer means by this. The context is just someone happy that they bought a tea mill.

Comment: While しまう can mean to "finish", in this grammatical usage after the て form of another verb, it means something happened unintentional, usually with negative connotations. Like "end up" in English.

Comment: See for example https://www.imabi.net/teshimau.htm for an overview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grammar of ～ちゃいましょう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54280/grammar-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%a1%e3%82%83%e3%81%84%e3%81%be%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86)

Answer (score 1):

そんな飲み方をしてしまいたくなる in this context means (O-cha Mill has such a quality that) you cannot help trying it to make (even) such an unusual drink as a matcha-ginger mix. しまう here indicates unconsciousness or spontaneity, not regret or completeness. The adverb つい would have made this meaning clearer.

してしまいたくなる can be replaced with したくなってしまう with little difference in meaning in this particular context. However, it could be ambiguous in others. For example, 食べてしまいたくなる could mean either something gives you a spontaneous craving, or something makes you want to finish your food. The second meaning is not possible with 食べたくなってしまう.

Answer (score 0):

「してしまいたくな」is just the てしまう form of したくなる

> そんな飲み方、え～ってかんじだけど、そんな飲み方をしてしまいたくなるのが、このお茶ミルです

This was of drinking might feel like "wha..?", but wanting to drink like this is what this tea mill is about.